# Is it possible for git to use $HOME instead /home/user when adding files?

Tags: git, environment-variables

I want to track all the important configuration files on my computer using git. I have files in `/etc` and files in `$HOME/.config`. I have a git repository with a working tree set to `/`. At the moment, I can do everything I want. The only issue I have is when I add a file such `$HOME/.config/file`, the filename gets expanded to `/home/user/.config/file`. The drawback to this is that I need to use the same username in all my computers. Is it possible to make git store the filename without expanding the environment variable `$HOME`?

Comment: When you write `git add $HOME/.config/file` (or something similar), Git does not even know that you use `$HOME` (or any other environment variable) to express the file path. It receives `add` and `/home/user/.config/file` as arguments. The shell does the replacement.

Comment: You are basically trying to use Git as a *deployment* tool: don't do that. It's fine to store files in a Git repository, but you should have a separate script to copy them from a Git checkout to the appropriate, machine-specific, locations.

Comment: I would advise you to be veeeery careful with a git directory initialized at `/`. For example : don't run `git clean -fd` in the wrong directory ... (since any directory on your disk will be treated as part of that checkout, `git clean` may act on *all your files on disk*)

Comment: I would recommend to have two separate repos. One for your home, one for etc. LeGEC's warning still stands.

Comment: I would not have a single Git repository in `/` but multiple repositories, one in `/etc`, another one in `/usr` and one in `$HOME` (whatever it expands to). Or multiple repositories for multiple user accounts. I did something similar several years ago and it worked fine with separate repositories in these directories. Set up carefully crafted `.gitignore` files in them, add remotes, write a simple script that does `git add; git commit; git push` in each of them, schedule it to run periodically and you get a simple backup tool.

Comment: I too have a simple shell alias in my dotfiles on GitHub to act as a management/control/backup solution for my configuration files. I'm sure it could be extended to detect the current parent directory and set its variables accordingly. (LeGEC's warning _still_ stands :))

Comment: I am reminded of [the Simpsons episode where Homer buys a gun, and starts firing bullets to flip the light switch on and off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cartridge_Family). You *can* use Git this way, but I sure wouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to separate the Git repository from its actual worktree (since the wortree is named after the user).

See "[dot-team: a new way of managing dotfiles](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2022/02/22/dot-team-0-1/)" from [Felipe Contreras](https://felipec.wordpress.com/about/)

```
alias config='git --git-dir=$DOTFILES/.git/ --work-tree=$HOME'
```

> With this trick it’s possible to have your git repository in a different directory than your work tree.
> That means your files are in $HOME, while your dotfiles’ git repository somewhere else. When you do `config diff` in your home directory, git knows where your dotfiles’ repository actually is.
>
> You can issue all git commands with the config command instead, and everything works almost magically (e.g. `config diff`, `config status`, `config add`, etc.).

```bash
  git repo (at $DOTFILES/.git)    Work Tree (at $HOME)
             |                          |
             V                          V
+-------------+-----------+    +--------+-------+--------+
| Dotfiles git repository |    | $HOME/.config  |  /etc  |
|                         |    |                |        |
|                         |    | Config files   | Config |
|                         |    | to track       | files  |
+-------------------------+    +----------------+--------+
             |
             |
             V
         config alias
    (git with custom dir and work-tree)
```

---

As noted by [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199541/is-it-possible-for-git-to-use-home-instead-home-user-when-adding-files/74203441#comment136389073_74203441):

> Just don't do `config clean -fdx`: it will wipe most files from your home directory

The [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) command is used to clean the working directory in Git by removing files that are not under version control.
The `-fdx` flags instruct Git to forcibly delete all untracked and ignored files, including those specified in the `.gitignore` file.

When you have set the work-tree to `$HOME`, running `config clean -fdx` will treat the entire home directory as the working directory for the Git repository.
As a result, it will attempt to delete all files and directories in `$HOME`(!) that are not under version control, which is highly destructive and likely not the intended action.

When it comes to [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), I always use the `-n`/`--dry-run` first. That way, you can see what will be done *before* the files are removed.

Comment: Just don't do `config clean -fdx`: it will wipe most files from your home directory

Comment: @knittl Good point, thank you for that feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with some additional explanation.